# nested structures using pointers - initialization and use

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

So I have a header file:

```
    struct inner1 {
        int w;
        int x;
};

    struct inner2 {
        int y;
        int z;
};
struct outer{
      inner1 *a;
      inner2 *b;
};
```

Now in main, I want to initialize these structures and use them.  How do I initialize all three structures so that outer recognizes inner1 and inner2 as the specific structs it points to. Then lets say I want to access the variable w. Is it outer.a->w? I am unfamiliar with nested structures dealing with pointers. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need to have pointers? Can you just declare them like
 `inner1 a;
  inner2 b;`

And use them like `o.a.w` ?

Comment: I'm working in a program that use this concept in a very large scale! It allocate and deallocate memory everywhere, because of it is a pain to debug... and when it breaks... If you are using it, please create documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct inner1 {
        int w;
        int x;
};

    struct inner2 {
        int y;
        int z;
};
struct outer{
      inner1 *a;
      inner2 *b;
};

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   outer o;
   o.a = new inner1();
   o.b = new inner2();
   o.a->w = 1;
   o.a->x = 2;
   o.b->y = 3;
   o.b->z = 4;
```

//do stuff

```
  delete o.a;
  delete o.b;

    return 0;
}
```

This will permit you to declare and initialize the structures.

Comment: This will crash since a and b are not initialized

Comment: @Ceros I thought the same, but to my surprise it does not. I still think it is undefined behaviour. `a` and `b` are just pointers, there still needs to be some memory allocated.

Comment: Exactly, undefined behavior. I don't think that by default they are assigned to `nullptr`

Comment: in reality my structures that would be inner1 and inner2 are very long with up to 20 fields. The inner structures will be used with the lseek and read system calls to read in data from a large file. I dont want to initialize each member within the structs, but rather initalize inners and assure that outer is pointing to these newly initialized structures, if that makes sense EDIT: ok i think what i wanted was that edit you made. thank you

Comment: @Ceros, yes you are right, I corrected my code. Thanks

Comment: @minusila not sure if I understand you right, but I am 99,9% that you dont need the pointers

Comment: You could also have constructors for your `inner1` and `inner2` structs, Ex. `struct inner1 {
        int w;
        int x;

        inner1(int a, int b)
        {
           w = a;
           x = b;
        };
};`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    struct inner1 {
        int w;
        int x;
    };

    struct inner2 {
        int y;
        int z;
    };

    struct outer{
        inner1 *a;
        inner2 *b;
    };

    outer o = { new inner1 { 10, 20 }, new inner2 { 30, 40 } };

    std::cout << "o.a->w = " << o.a->w << ", o.a->x = " << o.a->x
              << ", o.b->y = " << o.b->y << ", o.b->z = " << o.b->z
              << std::endl;

    delete o.a;
    delete o.b;
}
```

The program output is

```
o.a->w = 10, o.a->x = 20, o.b->y = 30, o.b->z = 40
```

Or you could do the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    struct inner1 {
        int w;
        int x;
    };

    struct inner2 {
        int y;
        int z;
    };

    struct outer{
        inner1 *a;
        inner2 *b;
    };

    inner1 i1 = { 10, 20 };
    inner2 i2 = { 30, 40 };

    outer o = { &i1, &i2 };

    std::cout << "o.a->w = " << o.a->w << ", o.a->x = " << o.a->x
              << ", o.b->y = " << o.b->y << ", o.b->z = " << o.b->z
              << std::endl;

}
```

The approach depends on the task and using of the objects.

Comment: It would be a lot cleaner if `o` had a constructor that took care of this for you, but maybe that's not the responsibility of this code.

Comment: @tadman I tried to use the code presented in the question.:) Of course for example I could use smart pointers as std::unique_ptr for the data members.

Comment: Yep! Just offering a way to improve this and make it a little less noisy. You certainly have a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in both your assumptions.

As long as these three structures are defined in this order no further declarations have to be made.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to c++.

The biggest favour you will do yourself is to learn about the smart pointers early on.

It's almost always a mistake to write structures in terms of raw pointers.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct inner1 {
    inner1(int a, int b) : w(a), x(b) {}
    int w;
    int x;
};

struct inner2 {
    inner2(int a, int b) : y(a), z(b) {}
    int y;
    int z;
};

struct outer{
    outer(int w, int x, int y, int z)
    : a(std::make_unique<inner1>(w,x))
    , b(std::make_unique<inner2>(y,z))
    {}

    std::unique_ptr<inner1> a;
    std::unique_ptr<inner2> b;
};

int main()
{
    auto p_outer = std::make_unique<outer>(1, 2, 3, 4);

    return 0;

    // p_outer.a and .b are destroyed automatically here
    // and all memory is reclaimed.
}
```

Comment: your outer only really seems realistic when there is only 4 fields. My real structures (there are 4 of) have over 20 fields a piece. I feel like you shouldn't have to rewrite every field of the structures?

Comment: @minusila there's no reason you couldn't pass in a set of complete structures in the constructor.